# MVVM Pattern with application services

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, service, prism

I am just developing a new WPF application using PRISM. I want to add some application services which will registered using IOC (Unity). My question comes on hor to design these services; Let's imagine that I have some devices to control, monitor, manage...I thought in creating a new IDeviceService but I do not know how to design the interface behaviour, it is, should I have a service instance per device or just one and pass the device Id as parameter?

Another question is what to put in Device model and what to put in Service? And finally, should the service update the model or should be the viewmodel instead?

Thanks!

Comment: Try something and come back when you have issues.

Comment: Thanks Will for your answer but it is a conceptual issue, not a technical issue. Of course, everything in software can be done well or bad and get it working... I am just asking what you consider is the best approach.

Comment: The best approach is to start coding :/  Put your application logic in your VM, your service logic in your service, and your data in your models.  Go forth and type.

Comment: It's up to you how to design your software. Just ask yourself whether this makes sense to have service instances for each device. There is not enough input to help you, your question is very abstract.

Answer (score 0):

Look at MediatR. Or create some app service classes.  Or create one class per usecase.  This just reduces app code in your view model.